# If random variables $X, Y$ have joint PDF $f(x, y) = g(x)h(y)$ for some functions $g$ and $h$ then $X, Y$ are independent?

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm reading [All of Statistics](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/all-of-statistics/) by Larry Wasserman, and I'm confused by Theorem 2.33:

> Suppose that the range of $X$ and $Y$ is a (possibly infinite)
>   rectangle. If $f(x, y) = g(x)h(y)$ for some functions $g$ and $h$ (not
>   necessarily probability density functions) then $X$ and $Y$ are
>   independent.

How can I prove this statement, or get some intuition behind it? Does this also mean that two dependent variables and two independent variables cannot have the same joint PDF?

Thank you!

Comment: The question should really be on CrossValidated... but I won't vote to close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes to both questions and you can prove them using Fubini's Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

@Kavi was right about Fubini's Theorem, but I wanted to write out a detailed solution:

If we fix $x$, note that

$$
f_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x, y) dy = g(x) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(y) dy
$$

By symmetry:

$$
f_Y(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x, y) dx = h(y) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x) dx
$$

Multiplying, we have:

\begin{align}
f_X(x) f_Y(y)
&= g(x)h(y) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(y) dy \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x) dx \\
&= f(x,y) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y) dx dy \\
&= f(x, y)
\end{align}

So $X, Y$ must be independent.